# Access 2010 calculated field reference from a textbox

Tags: ms-access

I am working on access I am stuck in a point.please help
i have a calculated field :

```
Sum(IIf(Format([Ref_Date],"yyyymm")
```

Between

```
Format(DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1),"yyyymm")
```

And

```
Format(Date(),"yyyymm"),1,0))
```

it is calculating automatically but I have a report filter tool where I will select the date, now I need to pass that date range(that is: user date range) into this function so that it should work for any dates.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this in VBA that will return true if the date is in the required range and you can then use that result to perform any other calculation.

```
Function InDateRange(RefDate As Date, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date) As Boolean

    If (RefDate >= StartDate) And (RefDate <= EndDate) Then InDateRange = True

End Function
```

You can use the function in the control source of a text box;

```
=IIF(InDateRange([txtRef],[txtStart],[txtEnd]),1,0)
```

where txtRef, txtStart and txtEnd are text boxes with the date values in.

Comment: i am using this date range in report filter tool where there  are 5 other boxes also so any of them can be used for  date range field, and i have to use it query filed, how can i achieve that...

Comment: start date and end date will come from textboxes